# Excel - Comparing Two columns to get a difference count

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

Scenario:

An Excel Workbook has 3 sheets.  Sheet1 has an 'original' list of users WHICH DOES NOT CHANGE, Sheet2 has a list of 'current' users which does change, Sheet3 has some totalled information, like the total number of users on Sheet1 who are still on Sheet2.

Problem:

I can flag and count those on Sheet1 who are no longer on Sheet2, and provide a total count on Sheet3 - this uses another column on Sheet1 and an IF statement - but I can't do that for those on Sheet2 who are not on Sheet1 (someone was added, say) because the Sheet1 information is overwritten weekly by a manual process.

Question:

How do I show, on Sheet3 and from Sheet3, the total count of the number of users on Sheet2 who are not on Sheet1 when I can't add a column to Sheet2?

Many thanks in advance for your consideration of this problem - NigeH

Further Info:

Sheet1 ColumnA Rows 1-10 - Enter any 10 first names you want.
Sheet2 ColumnA Rows 1-10 - Enter 8 of the names from Sheet1 and 2 new ones.
Sheet3 - without using any new fields on Sheet1 or Sheet2 - and preferably only one field on Sheet3 - show the count of names on Sheet2 that aren't on Sheet1.

Comment: You should show us a sample from the three sheets.

Comment: So basically you want a count of Users that are not on sheet 1 but on sheet 2 displayed on sheet 3 ... Do the users have something unique ? A username ? Can we MB GET to see your excel? Because to know the structure of data would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this array formula (assumes your lists are in column A in both sheets) ...

```
{=COUNTA(Sheet2!$A:$A)-SUM(IF(ISERROR(MATCH(Sheet2!$A:$A,Sheet1!$A:$A,0)),0,1))}
```

If you want to show the users that aren't on Sheet1 on Sheet3, fill down this formula ...

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(Sheet2!$A1,Sheet1!$A:$A,0)),Sheet2!$A1,"")
```

Comment: From your array formula, I'm trying to modify and use the latter element 'SUM(IF(ISERROR(MATCH(Sheet2!$A:$A,Sheet1!$A:$A,0)),0,1))' but it keeps giving me '1' instead of the known '3' that I have ...

Comment: found my typo using your original array formula (once I'd got it in Excel correctly) but getting 30 instead of 3 - which isn't to say it's wrong !

Comment: Thank you OldUgly - your array formula works for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have a quick solution not so clever but works.
You will need 2 heaping columns. One column to get all users names from Sheet2 
In Sheet3 in cell A1  you should write:

```
=Sheet2!A1
```

You should copy this in all cells from A1 to A(user name count);
Then in Sheet3 in cell B1 write:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1),"",VLOOKUP(Sheet2!A:A,Sheet1!A:A,1,FALSE))
```

You should copy this in all cells from B1 to B(user name count) NOT MORE;
And finally in  Sheet3 in cell C1 you will have your count if you write:

```
=COUNTIF(B:B, NA())
```

If I get smarter way will edint.